# Javascript setTimeout reliability & DOM rendering

Tags: javascript, typescript, rendering, settimeout, event-loop

I am using Angular and I have a modal component. The modal has an ngIf and it shows when it's true. I have some default buttons in the modal. I need to set focus on a non specific button inside this modal when it opens. The problem is that the button doesn't exist (it isn't rendered to the DOM) when the "open" function is called, but only after it is finished.

The only solution that worked for me was setTimeout(()=>{ // focus }, 0).

```
  open() {
    this.modal.open();

    setTimeout(x => {
      const btnToFocus = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.some-button');
      btnToFocus.focus();
    }, 0);
  }
```

How can I be certain that the code above is reliable?

In my understanding, once the function is completed, and the ngIf is set to true, some rendering tasks (say A,B,C) should be sent to the event loop stack. (after that, the button will exist and will be found with the querySelector)
Let's mark the function used in setTimeout as X.
I imagine that when the "open" function is completed, the stack would have A,B,C,X

Can anyone could shed some light on what's happening in the event loop once the function is completed? how do the rendering tasks work and when?

Comment: why not always render the modal, and toggle whether the modal is visible in the `open()`? then the button will always exist and you don't have to do a hacky setTimeout.

Comment: @RyanCastner Because of performance issues. I have multiple modals. Some of them have to send server calls when initialized.